# ECS + Zookeeper - Does zookeeper have to be dockerized

Tags: docker, containers, apache-zookeeper, amazon-ecs, service-discovery

I'm currently working on dockerizing my microservices. Currently they are hosted on ec2 and i plan to move them to ecs. My question here is about service discovery for which i use zookeeper. My zookeeper is also hosted on ec2. Do i have to dockerize zookeeper and move it to ecs for my dockerized microservices to work? Or can my dockerized microservices on ecs can still do discovery with zookeeper on ec2? The docs are not very intuitive, so would like some advice on this.

Answer (score 0):

Service discovery should only care about the ZK hosts and ports, so whether it's running in a Docker container or on bare metal shouldn't make a difference.